# The optical encoder resolution

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, motors, gears, dynamics

The optical encoder has a code wheel with a single track of slots and two photodetectors. The photodetectors are positioned so that they produce signals with a 90 degree phase difference.

I want to calculate how many slots there has to be in the code wheel in each of the following cases in order to measure the position of the linearly moving object with a resolution of 0.02 mm.

Case 1:
motor + gear + ball screw ($p=8 \text{mm}$)

Case 2: motor + gear + conveyor belt ($d = 38 \text{mm} $)

in both cases the gear ratio is 6.5.

Is it simple as this:

$$\frac{8}{0.02\cdot 6.5}=62$$

and

$$\frac{19}{0.02\cdot6.5}= 146$$

so needed slot are 62 and 146.

Is this wrong and if it is how do I calculate this?

Comment: You're definitely on the right track! it would be good to clarify a little bit, but if p is pitch then you are correct for the ball screw. If d is the diameter of your drive pulley on the belt, then you are missing a compensation for the circumference of the circle. your number should be 38 * pi/ (.02*6.5). Note that all of this is theoretical accuracy, and since there are other sources of error like belt stretch, picking this encoder resolution doesn't mean you'll actually be able to position anything within 0.02mm

Comment: Yes p is the pitch and the d is diameter of the pulley on the belt. So the case 1 = 62 and the case 2 = 918. Yeah this is only theoretical model.